# Gradle with ModuleVersionNotFoundException - org.jacoco.agent

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have android project just migrate from intellij to android studio as Gradle project.

Previously work well in intellij as ant project, now it successfully build with Gradle, but I can't figure out why I get Exception when I run & compile apk.

I don't use org.jacoco.agent

Why gradle complaint this & how to solve this?
I tried to add dependency:

> compile group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', version: '0.7.5.201505241946'

and even download the jar file put in my library, during run & compile apk show me same error.

Appreciate any suggestions & guidance.
Thanks a lot!

Exception show:

> Error:org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.5.201505241946.

Gradle Console show:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':androidJacocoAgent'.
>     Could not find org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.5.201505241946.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>       file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>       file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>     Required by:
>       :Obriens Delivery:unspecified
> - Try:
>     Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is:
>     org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':androidJacocoAgent'.
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:62)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.java:112)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:189)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:669)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:293)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:65)
>     at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.JacocoAgentConfigAction$1.call(JacocoAgentConfigAction.java:63)
>     at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.JacocoAgentConfigAction$1.call(JacocoAgentConfigAction.java:59)
>     at org.gradle.util.GUtil.uncheckedCall(GUtil.java:401)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.add(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.add(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:79)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.add(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:79)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:91)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitDependencies(CompositeFileCollection.java:156)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitDependencies(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:97)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$1.visitDependencies(CompositeFileCollection.java:106)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree$FilteredFileTree.visitDependencies(CompositeFileTree.java:107)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:88)
>     at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:202)
>     at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:112)
>     at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:64)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.doResolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:76)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:65)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:55)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.addToTaskGraph(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:139)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.addTasks(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:98)
>     at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
>     at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
>     at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
>     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.5.201505241946.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>     file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>     file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>     file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>     file:/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>     file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>     file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>     Required by:
>     :Obriens Delivery:unspecified
>     at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.java:38)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:88)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:59)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:80)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:44)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:564)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:574)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:260)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:234)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:141)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:79)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:90)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:80)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:80)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:41)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>     at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
>     at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
>     at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
>     at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:91)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.java:40)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolve(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:52)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:43)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:372)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:347)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:340)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:667)
>     ... 83 more

build.gradle with:

> ```
> buildscript {
>         repositories {
>             mavenCentral()
>         }
>         dependencies {
>             classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
>         }
>     }
>     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>     dependencies {
>         compile files('./libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
>         compile files('./libs/android-support-v4.jar')
>     }
>     android {
>         compileSdkVersion 25
>         buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
>         useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
>         sourceSets {
>             main {
>                 manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
>                 java.srcDirs = ['src']
>                 resources.srcDirs = ['src']
>                 aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
>                 renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
>                 res.srcDirs = ['res']
>                 assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
>             }
>         }
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.hoelee.obriens_delivery"
>         minSdkVersion 14
>         targetSdkVersion 21
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.63"
>         jackOptions {
>             enabled true
>         }
>     }
>     compileOptions {
>         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Settings -> Gradle -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Offline work. Check if is unmarked.

Comment: Do you mean set Gradle go offline? Tested go offline, give same error.